# max.compaction.lag.ms for topics with retention of 7 days

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, stream-compaction

I want to add compaction to our topics, which configured to keep logs for 7 days max.
I noticed the `max.compaction.lag.ms` has higher value than 7 days, what is the downside of setting this parameter to a lower value (around 12 hours) and is there any recommended value to go with the retention period?

Thanks